# For what condition the following differential equation has unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system

Let me define it first
We have a differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=A(t)x(t)+B(t)u(t)+f(x(t),u(t),t)$
where $X=(x_1,x_2,.....,x_n)$, $A(t) \mbox{ and } B(t)$ is an $n\times n $ variable matrix,$u(t)=(u_1(t),u_2(t),....,u_n(t))$, I want condition of $f(x(t),u(t),t)$ such the given differential equation has a unique solution.I have read somewhere that if $f(x(t),u(t),t)$ satisfy the lipschitz condition with respect to $x$ and $u$ then this differential equation will have uniques solution but I don't have any idea that how to get this.If someone can help or give some hint that will be helpful.Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is your problem?

Comment: Conditions on $f$ won't be enough as there will be problems when $A(t)$ (or $B(t)$ or $u(t)$) is discontinuous for example. Also I don't see how this is different to the general case because $f$ could satisfy $f(x,u,t)=-A(t)x-B(t)u+g(x,u,t)$, leaving you with the general case $\dot{x}=g(x,u,t)$. Uniqueness conditions for this case are given by the Picard–Lindelöf theorem.

Comment: The dependence on time can be relaxed to piecewise continuous in many cases but you will have to consider mild solutions, and not strong ones.

Comment: Yes, I understand both explanations. We just put a minimum condition on &dx/dt=f(x,u,t)=−A(t)x−B(t)u+g(x,u,t) & as a piecewise continuous and Lipschitz condition with respect to "x" according to  Picard–Lindelöf theorem.